# Passing strings directly into functions

Tags: c, string, function, parameters

Is it bad practice to directly pass strings into functions?

Will it cause memory errors?

```
func(char *x) {
   //do stuff
}

func("String");
```

Or is it safer to do this?

```
char *s = "string";
func(s);
```

Comment: There's no difference in the safety.  If `func()` — what's its return type — modifies the string, all hell will (probably) break loose if the string it is given is in fact a string literal, whether that's passed via the pointer `s` or not.  If `func()` doesn't modify the string, why isn't the argument declared `void func(const char *x)`?

Comment: @Delonous  The both calls are wrong and unsafe.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will it cause memory errors?

It might if you try to modify this string.

To be safe declare your function

```
func(const char *x) {
```

But there is nothing wrong in passing string literals to the functions. Otherwise 99.99 of programs are badly written.

> Or is it safer to do this?
>
> ```
> char *s = "string";
> func(s);
> ```

It does not change anything as you pass the pointer to the same string literal

But the code below is safe as you allocate RW (read/write) memory to accommodate the string, and system copies that literal into this allocated space

```
 char s[] = "string";
 func(s);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func(char *x) {
   //do stuff
}
```

this function takes a pointer on a string as input. The interface allows to read & write from `x` pointed data.

*but* since you're using a *string literal* (in both cases of your examples), it's illegal to modify the memory of this string literal (and most compilers, ex `gcc` organize code/data in a way that prevents you from doing that: SEGV)

The "safe" way (as long as you don't go out of string bounds when writing - or reading of course -):

```
char s[] = "string";
func(s);
```

or if you're not planning to modify the contents of `s` in `func`, declare the pointer as `const`:

```
func(const char *x)
```